# what is a fetch execution cycle

Tags: data-structures, cpu

I was wondering if someone could explain what a fetch execution cycle is and what are the steps involved.

I have been looking up online and get definitions like

"An instruction cycle (sometimes called fetch-decode-execute cycle) is the basic operation cycle of a computer. It is the process by which a computer retrieves a program instruction from its memory, determines what actions the instruction requires, and carries out those actions."

But Could someone break this down a bit further and explains the steps involved executing a fetch execution cycle?

Comment: This is a great visual explanation: https://youtu.be/FZGugFqdr60?list=PL8dPuuaLjXtNlUrzyH5r6jN9ulIgZBpdo&t=92

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to explain however i don't have all correct English terms, I think this is related to the operation pointer.

Every program have states which are in the registry of the CPU when they're executed, meaning not in a pending state by the scheduler. One of the values stored is the current value of the operation pointer. This pointer contains the memory address in the RAM of the next operation to execute.

So the computer read that value, use his "memory bus" (probably not the right term) to fetch the operation to execute from the memory, then execute it.

Then the operation pointer will contains the next operation to execute, either the next one or another if the operation was to move the operation pointer.

Note than an "operation" is just a raw value in memory it's the cpu that translate it to a "physical"/"logical" operation.